# How far can radio waves travel in vacuum? and light waves?

Tags: visible-light, waves, photons, space, radio

Radio wave and light wave are the same thing. They all are electromagnetic radiation, the only difference between them is frequency.
My question :
1, is there any photon-like thing for radio wave?
2, how far can they travel in vacuum space?

Thanks

Comment: all electromagnetic radiation is composed out of superposition of photons https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Electromagnetic_spectrum

Answer (score 1):

Radio waves are like other frequency E&M radiation in that they can travel infinitely far in a vacuum at the speed c. c = 2.998x10^8 m/sec.
Photons can have the frequency associated with the radio frequency.

Answer (score -1):

Radio waves are just a less energetic version of infra red or visible light, so like the other wavelengths they have a particle aspect (photons) as well as a wave aspect. Nobody really understands wave/particle duality, you can only see whichever aspect your equipment is designed to detect. As to how far they can travel in a vacuum, the electromagnetic force reaches to infinity. Radio waves are part of the electromagnetic spectrum, so the answer is any distance you care to mention. I think the furthest yet detected by radio telescopes have travelled nearly 14 billion miles. Bear in mind that at distances of billions of miles, photons become red-shifted due to the expansion of the universe, so may not have started out as radio waves. Other factors such as gravity can also red shift them. Space is not a perfect vacuum, which doesn't make much difference for distances of under a billion miles, but probably does for distances far greater than that.

Comment: PS The classic example of waves behaving like particles is the photo electric effect, where high energy photons knock electrons out of a metal plate, but radio waves are far too weak to do anything like that. Einstein's Nobel Prize was for his 1905 paper on the photoelectric effect.

Comment: OTOH, radio waves can make the electrons in a piece of metal wiggle around. If they couldn't do that, radios wouldn't work.

Comment: Where does that figure of 14 billion miles come from? That's not very far, around 150 AU.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no telescope or radio telescope has detected electromagnetic waves from more than 13.8 billion miles away; if they have, they certainly haven't trumpeted the fact.

Comment: Space is not an absolute vacuum. When photon travels, it must hit some particals and becomes less energetic. This leads to red-shift. If phonon travels too far, the red-shift must be enormous. And the phonon will disappear finally.

Comment: The nearest star system is Alpha Centauri, at a distance of 4.367 light years, or 25.67 *trillion* miles. We can detect light and radio waves from billions of light years away. The most distant electromagnetic energy detectable is the cosmic microwave background radiation, which has been traveling for over 13.7 billion years. Distance measurement gets complicated on cosmological scales, due to the expansion of the universe.

Comment: @CangYe Cosmological expansion is the main cause of the redshift of radiation from distant sources. BTW, phonons are not the same as photons.

Comment: Thanks PM 2Ring. Cosmological extension assumption is based on observed red-shift.  we must exclude any other possible redshift cause other than relative moving.